# Command does not work in script file, but works ok with shell command

Tags: bash, unix

I have a script here that when executed in shell command it produces the output I am expecting

```
greatwall:nobody:/v6/centera/cnaccs> ./consDownload.cgi 277756541642 5 0
CI,JPJA,ETD,0b0dbba1d2f1278H,202209081947|CO,JPJA,ETD,0b0dbba1d2f1278H,202209081947|AWB,JPJA,ETD,0b0dbba1d2f1278H,202209081947|
```

But when the same command was executed inside a shell script it encountered an error

Line inside shell script

```
op=$(./consDownload.cgi "$AWB" "5" "0" 2>&1)
timeStamp "op=$op"
```

Error from logs

```
op=./consDownload.cgi: line 148: openssl: command not found
```

line 148 from consDownload script

```
OPENSSL="openssl"
AUTHZID="APP83"
SERVICEID="APP5285"
PRIVATEKEY="./app83.pem"
TOKEN="$(echo -n "$SERVICEID:$(TZ=Asia/Singapore date +%s)000" | "$OPENSSL" rsautl -inkey "$PRIVATEKEY" -sign -pkcs | base64 -w 0)"
TOKEN="v1:$AUTHZID:$TOKEN:$AUTHZID"
```

but when I checked, openssl is installed on server

```
greatwall:nobody:/v6/centera/cnaccs> openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2q  20 Nov 2018
```

Comment: Is the script being ran through cron or manually?

Comment: its being executed manually

Comment: Just for a sanity check, could you add `echo $PATH` to the script to make sure it's still properly set?

Comment: I also did that, but same result

Comment: What was the output of $PATH?

Comment: /bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin

Comment: What if you hard code the full path to openssl in the script?

Comment: Run `which openssl` and make sure the path for openssl is included in your PATH variable you commented above.

Comment: @Bjawww Can you show us `which openssl` or `type openssl` as Nic3500 asked?